# Grails - handling authentication

Tags: grails, spring-security

**Currently how my application works**
User comes to the site performs some tasks. On click of a button on a page if the user is not logged in the user is taken back to login page, where the user will have to either login or register.

In controller method there is Secured annotation which maps to "auth" of DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy and is directed to login page.

**What needs to be changed / achieved**
Currently it simply redirects to a controller/method where I lose the original request. I need to write my own handler which will do some action on the request object and then redirect to controller/method.

I don't know how to.
1. write my own handler.
2. Will I need to override auth of DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy in my SecurityConfig.grooy so that it calls my handler 1st

I am very new to Grails so please bear with me and try to suggest solution in detail.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787790/grails-spring-security-saved-request-empty-parameters-and-unbound-command

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I will go through your link now.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore, i think the post suggested by you might work for me. I am going to try it now. If it works nothing like it as i have a delivery on friday. Thanks in advance for the quick help.